# How to apply signalr to different urls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

Looking at this jQuery format below, I used signalr to broadcast live content in a certain view.

So far, I can just broadcast a content in realtime in just one specific view, which is **'/MyController/MyActionMethod'**.

Now I have two more views to broadcast the same content as I did on the first view, which are

- **'/MyController2/MyActionMethod2';** and
- **'/MyController3/MyActionMethod3';** respectively.

The jQuery code below is being referenced in the first view, now I added some syntax like to enable the same code on the other two views:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1334/MyController2/MyActionMethod2';  
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1334/MyController3/MyActionMethod3';
```

but this code doesn't do anything.

What am I missing here? Is there anything I need to add? Do I need also to reference that code in the two views as well? Please advise, thanks.

```
$(function() { 
    // Save the reference to the SignalR hub 
    var comHub = $.connection.commentHub;
    comHub.client.newContent = function () {
        // Sample functions to refresh the page based on information coming 
        // from the server.
        RefreshPage();
        UpdateContent();

    };

    // Invoke the function to be called back from the server 
    // when changes are detected  

    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1334/MyController2/MyActionMethod2';
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1334/MyController3/MyActionMethod3';

    // Start the SignalR client-side listener
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
  $("#pushbutton").click(function () {
    //...some function to trigger here
})

})

})
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? I mean, you are broadcasting some data to the result of the action /MyController/MyActionMethod? Now you want the same data to be broadcasted to 2 more views? Where does the code that you posted belong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking and you don't need to add these two lines of code:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1334/MyController2/MyActionMethod2';
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1334/MyController3/MyActionMethod3';
```

`$.connection.hub.url` is used to override the route URL which clients use to connect to your Hub, as explained [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#signalrurl) (and anyway the second line override the first).

What you need to do is to add the code that connect to the SignalR Hub in all the three views that need to receive data and manage how this data is handled.